# Click a link based on the value of another column in the row

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium and am trying to design a test where Selenium identifies the order I want to access based on the value of another column in the row on the page.

The page I am testing does not store records in any stable order, and I need to click on the link for the record that is in a "Not Yet Processed" status.

In the HTML formatting, is there a way for me to have Selenium read all of the rows looking for the row in "Not Yet Processed" status, and then click on the link 4 columns over to access that orders page? (The ultimate goal is to make a test that can place an order, and then go and cancel the order it just placed).

Comment: is there any html to see? might be simpler for us

Comment: I think that FindElements is going to be the way to go with this.  You can use FindElements on the column that contains "Not Yet Processed", get the index of the WebElement that contains the text.  Then FindElements on the column with the link, and click the WebElement[index].

Answer (score 0):

Try if the following gives an idea for what your looking,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
By webElementLocatorBy = By.id("your table id");
By webTextLocatorBy = By.id("your coloumn id");
WebElement table = driver.get("your URL").findElement(webElementLocatorBy);
List<WebElement> tableRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (int row = 0; row < tableRows.size(); row++) {
   if ("Not Yet Processed".equals(driver.get("your URL").findElement(webTextLocatorBy)).getText()) {
       // do your stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click checkbox based on values, you have to list all values using for loop and checkbox absolute xpath and pass "i"   value.

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id ='content']/table"));
/*List <WebElement> head = driver.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
head.size();

for (int h=0;h<head.size();h++){*/
List <WebElement> row = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
row.size();

for (int i=0;i<row.size();i++){
    List <WebElement> col = row.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    col.size();

    for (int j=0;j<col.size();j++){
        String cv = col.get(j).getText();
        // If name is Saudi Arabia, it will click on check box 
        if(cv.equalsIgnoreCase("Saudi Arabia")){
            // Divide the x path where colunm is changing html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[pass i value]/td[6]";
            String xp1 = "html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[";
            String xp2 = "]/td[6]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the table for "Not Yet Processed" and click on a link in some cell in the same row.  The following code snippet chooses the field that just **precedes** the cell with the text. The "1" can be changed to choose cells further to the left.  Note, if the "a" is not present at the end of the xpath search string, selenium will not click the link - even if you use the correct index.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(text(), "Not Yet Processed")]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/a")
link.click()
```

If the link is to the right of the text in the table, use "following" instead of "preceding".

Best Regards,

Derrel